# Password generator in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here's a password generator I created.

```
### THIS PROGRAM WAS CREATED FOR LEARNING PURPOSES  ###
###   AND SHOULD NOT BE USED TO CREATE PASSWORDS!   ###

import string
from enum import Enum
from random import randint, shuffle, choice

class PasswordError(Exception):
    __module__ = Exception.__module__

# Types of characters possible
class Types(Enum):
    CAP = 'CAP' # Capital
    SMA = 'SMA' # Small
    DIG = 'DIG' # Digits
    SPE = 'SPE' # Special

# Characters for each type of possible characters
type_chars = {
    Types.CAP: string.ascii_uppercase,
    Types.SMA: string.ascii_lowercase,
    Types.DIG: string.digits,
    Types.SPE: '!()-.?[]_`~;:@#$%^&*='
}

def password_generator(min_length=6, max_length=20, caps=1, small=1, digits=1, special=1):
    types = {
        Types.CAP: caps,
        Types.SMA: small,
        Types.DIG: digits,
        Types.SPE: special,
    }

    num_chars = sum(list(types.values())) # Number of mandatory characters
    min_length = max(num_chars, min_length) # In case 'num_chars' is greater

    # Number of characters required for each possible type of character
    # Is greater than maximum possible length
    if min_length > max_length:
        raise PasswordError(f'No password with the given criteria')

    length = randint(min_length, max_length)

    # List that stores the "types" of possible character
    char_list = []

    # Mandatory requirements
    for typ, val in zip(types.keys(), types.values()):
        char_list.extend([typ] * val)

    # The remaining values to fill
    for rem in range(length - num_chars):
        char_list.append(choice(list(types.keys())))

    shuffle(char_list)

    password = ''

    for typ in char_list:
        password += choice(type_chars[typ])

    return password

if __name__ == '__main__':
    min_length = int(input('Minimum number of characters required: '))
    max_length = int(input('Maximum number of characters possible: '))

    print()

    caps = int(input('Number of capital letters required: '))
    small = int(input('Number of small letters required: '))
    digits = int(input('Number of digits required: '))
    special = int(input('Number of special characters required: '))

    print()

    number = int(input('Number of passwords required: '))

    print('\n' + '-' * 50 + '\n')
    print('   Here are your passwords: \n')

    for i in range(number):
        print(password_generator(min_length, max_length, caps, small, digits, special))
```

You can also modify the mandatory types of characters (Like 3 caps, 2 digits, etc). Also, minimum length and maximum length can be specified.

I think this code looks a bit ugly. How do I improve this?

Comment: Please note that [Official Guidelines](https://spycloud.com/new-nist-guidelines/) state that *requiring* special character classes results in bad passwords. The only difference it makes it that it turns all `password` into `Password123!` instead, which add exactly zero security.

Comment: @Gloweye I didn't quite know that! I just based of my program from my experience with websites that said 'weak' for `password` and 'medium' for `Password123!` and 'strong' for `P@ssword$123!`

Comment: @Gloweye regardless, many sites still require special characters. This tool generates passwords. OP is not asking advice for what rules to use for a site they control.

Comment: I'd suggest including a warning in the output (or at least in the source as a comment) that this is (probably) *not* safe for real use; you're not a crypto expert.  Neither am I, but I know enough to be cautious about where my random numbers come from (does Python make sure to seed its RNG from /dev/random or similar?  Maybe but IDK), and that there are some agreed-upon standards for generating passwords for humans.

Comment: @CaptainMan Many sites have crappy password standards. I didn't say this program was bad because of it, but it's something people should be aware of. (But please to note that special character *should* be allowed in passwords - forbidding them is even less secure than forcing.)

Comment: @PeterCordes You should read AlexV's answer below. Python has the `secrets` module for cryptographic-quality random numbers.

Comment: @Gloweye Yes, I agree with you. I wasn't aware of it till when you posted the official guidelines. Thanks for posting it!

Comment: @Gloweye: yeah, I saw that after commenting.  Probably I'm being overcautious, and nobody would take security-critical code from *questions* posted on codereview, but it might still be a good idea to make the first line a warning comment like `# don't use for real passwords; this is a toy program as a learning exercise`

Comment: @PeterCordes Done!

Comment: @PeterCordes Never underestimate the cross section of laziness and ignorance that could lead to people copying random internet code. If Alex's answer hadn't been there, I'd have mentioned the secrets module right away as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### *Refactoring in steps*

***Enumeration class***

`Types` is too generic name for the *enum* representing *char types*. Renamed to **`CharTypes`**.
Instead `CAP`, `SMA`, `DIG`, `SPE` as *enumeration members* are better replaced with a more common/familiar and comprehensive abbreviations/associations:
`UPPER`, `LOWER`, `DIGIT` and `SPECIAL`.
Since `string.ascii_uppercase` and other `string.*` are essentially just *string constants* - they can be easily set as *enumeration values*:

```
class CharTypes(Enum):
    UPPER = string.ascii_uppercase     # Capital
    LOWER = string.ascii_lowercase     # Small
    DIGIT = string.digits              # Digits
    SPECIAL = '!()-.?[]_`~;:@#$%^&*='  # Special
```

thus, making all intermediate re-mappings like `type_chars` and `types` (in `password_generator` function) redundant and unnecessary.

---

***`password_generator`*** function

The function signature is slightly changed in arguments names to conform with `CharTypes` members:

```
def password_generator(min_length=6, max_length=20, upper=1, lower=1, digits=1, special=1)
```

`types` mapping is eliminated as redundant.

*char counts* passed as arguments are gathered and summed at once:

```
char_counts = (upper, lower, digits, special)
num_chars = sum(char_counts)
```

Avoid overwriting/assigning to function argument like `min_length = max(num_chars, min_length)` as **`min_length`** might be potentially referenced as *"original"* argument value (and relied on) in other places in the function's body.
A safer way is assigning it to a separate variable:

```
min_len = max(num_chars, min_length)
```

`length` variable is renamed to **`target_length`** (to emphasize the *final* size).

`char_list` is renamed to **`char_types`** as it's aimed to accumulate `CharTypes` enum members

Two `for` loops which performed `char_list.extend` and `char_list.append` are efficiently replaced with 2 *generators* which further joined/merged by [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) function:

```
char_types = list(chain(*([c_type] * num for c_type, num in zip(CharTypes, char_counts)),
                        (choice(char_types_enums) for _ in range(target_length - num_chars))))
```

Furthermore, `itertools.chain` is smart enough to skip *empty* generators (if let's say there's no *remaining values to fill*).

The last `for` loop (accumulating password from random chars) is simply replaced with `str.join` call on generator expression:

```
password = ''.join(choice(char_type.value) for char_type in char_types)
```

---

The whole crucial functionality is now shortened to the following:

```
import string
from enum import Enum
from random import randint, shuffle, choice
from itertools import chain


class PasswordError(Exception):
    pass


class CharTypes(Enum):
    UPPER = string.ascii_uppercase     # Capital
    LOWER = string.ascii_lowercase     # Small
    DIGIT = string.digits              # Digits
    SPECIAL = '!()-.?[]_`~;:@#$%^&*='  # Special


def password_generator(min_length=6, max_length=20, upper=1, lower=1, digits=1, special=1):
    char_counts = (upper, lower, digits, special)
    num_chars = sum(char_counts)   # Number of mandatory characters
    min_len = max(num_chars, min_length)   # In case 'num_chars' is greater

    # If number of characters required for each possible char type
    # is greater than maximum possible length
    if min_len > max_length:
        raise PasswordError(f'No password with the given criteria')

    target_length = randint(min_len, max_length)
    char_types_enums = list(CharTypes)  # get list of enums to pass `random.choice` call

    # List of char "types" comprised of: mandatory requirements + remaining values to fill
    char_types = list(chain(*([c_type] * num for c_type, num in zip(CharTypes, char_counts)),
                            (choice(char_types_enums) for _ in range(target_length - num_chars))))
    shuffle(char_types)

    password = ''.join(choice(char_type.value) for char_type in char_types)
    return password


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ....
```

Sample usage:

```
Minimum number of characters required: >? 10
Maximum number of characters possible: >? 30
Number of capital letters required: >? 5
Number of small letters required: >? 4
Number of digits required: >? 6
Number of special characters required: >? 5
Number of passwords required: >? 4
--------------------------------------------------

   Here are your passwords: 

32S%km3A^v04h9pwR-T7O;=0O
mh8a:38Q-pGS3PtGs)e0P1g)$(#0U1
z@a0r;b7v.~K!8S@R343J7L
Mie:8Ec0C=3Cz93HPHDFm_84#;6@
```

Comment: Yes, treating incoming args as const is often considered good style especially in a function of non-trivial size (and if nothing else makes debugging easier).  But the choice of names is problematic here: `min_len` vs. `min_length` are visually very similar.  A reader looking at some part of the function could easily miss that it was reading a different var name, not the arg.  Naming is hard, especially when you need multiple variables with similar semantic meaning/purpose but holding different values.

Comment: -1 for not using `secrets`

Comment: @GregSchmit-ReinstateMonica, You would need to figure out one simple thing - I didn't review a cryptography but the codebase.  But at least you've downvoted openly, although not very convincingly, in my opinion

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I did figure that out. Using `secrets` rather than `random` when writing a **PASSWORD GENERATOR** doesn't take a cryptographer, just a code reviewer :) -- BTW, I know I can be strident, but my downvote is not personal. If you edit your answer to use `secrets` then I will upvote you very quickly!

Comment: @GregSchmit-ReinstateMonica, The best I can advise to you is to spend your energy and efforts for writing your own answer with a new implementation based on `secrets` to express your idea more extensively and convincing the people how the best answer should look like. Thanks.

Comment: AlexV already wrote an answer using `secrets` (why it has more upvotes), but yours is the accepted answer so it would be good to use `secrets` on yours as well. I'm sorry you're offended that you didn't know to use that module when generating secrets.

Comment: @GregSchmit-ReinstateMonica while recommending `secrets` would improve the quality, I don't see in this answer where `random` is specifically recommended. [Answers need not cover every issue in every line of the code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), and if an answer skips over certain components, I don't think that invalidates the rest of the answer. Is `secrets` the way to go for the cryptography? Absolutely. Is that relevant for *this specific answer*? I don't think so, especially since AlexV covered that bit perfectly in their answer

Comment: @C.Nivs Ok, and I also note that reading back what I wrote, I realize I sound like a jerk. I just figured that crypto should be important for a password generator. It's like seeing a code review for a SSH server where the review doesn't mention that the implementation doesn't check host keys at all, so anyone could MITM the implementation. But now we want to have it be the top-listed code review because they optimized some some list comprehensions and renamed some variables.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Sorry for my "I'm sorry you're offended..." comment. That was jerky.

Comment: Fair point as that may be, it's not outside reason to see OP's mention *this looks ugly* and not go for some style recommendations. If I were to tackle this, I'd go for the style and organization stuff largely because I'm no expert at crypto (I learned about `secrets` through this question :) ). So, I'd leave the crypto stuff to the experts there, and offer the advice I can speak to. I'd argue it's *really* poor form to offer bad advice rather than none at all

Comment: @C.Nivs Ok, fair enough, but that's the whole point of the `secrets` module. It would be silly of me to criticize him for not manually feeding ambient temperature data into the password-generation process, because if he tried to do that as a non-cryptographer, he could easily screw it up and make the resulting password less random. The `secrets` module is explicitly a user-friendly tool to provide non-cryptographers an interface for generating secrets. But I take your point that if one didn't know about the `secrets` module, then one wouldn't know it's meant for non-cryptographers.

Answer (score 23):

The [other](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/232910/92478) [answers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/232913/92478) have great hints that you should definitely follow.

However, since we are talking about passwords here, a little bit of extra security might not hurt. Especially if it's readily available in the [`secrets`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html) module in Python 3. `secrets` uses a cryptograhically strong random number generator (in contrast to the *pseudo* random number generator in the normal `random` module). There is a special warning in that regard in the [docs of random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html). If you want to stick to `random`, at least use an instance of [`random.SystemRandom()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.SystemRandom), which is basically what `secrets` does. An example:

```py
RNG = random.SystemRandom()

def password_generator(...):
    ...
    # The remaining values to fill
    type_ = list(types.keys())
    for rem in range(length - num_chars):
        char_list.append(RNG.choice(type_))
        # alternatively
        char_list.append(secrets.choice(type_))
    ...
```

`random.choice` uses what is called a pseudo-random number generator, i.e. an algorithm that generates a deterministic "randomly looking" sequence of bytes starting from a given seed. `secrets.choice` uses a randomness source implemented in the OS, which likely takes electrical noise and other things into consideration to generate non-deterministic random data. random.org has a comprehensive article on the differences at https://www.random.org/randomness/. And of course, there is also the obligatory Wikipedia page about [Randomness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation).

Comment: Great answer! But can I ask why `secrets.choice` is cryptographically stronger than `random.choice`? The random library page doesn't quite explain it.

Comment: +1 for secrets. This is important information. Since other answer lack it, this is the best answer.

Comment: Sorry this wasn't the accepted answer. This really was a great answer and a great point, but it mostly improves the output cryptographically, but does not improve the code as a whole which @RomanPerekhrest's answer does.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few things I'd suggest to clean up the code.

First, you should be able to write the following

```py
for typ, val in zip(types.keys(), types.values()):
    char_list.extend([typ] * val)
```

without using `zip` by doing as follows

```py
for typ, val in types.items():
    char_list.extend([typ] * val)
```

#### Comprehensions

Comprehensions are a great way to clean up.

The first case would be

```py
for rem in range(length - num_chars):
    char_list.append(choice(list(types.keys())))
```

as

```py
char_list.extend([choice(list(types.keys())) for _ in range(length - num_chars)])
```

And a second time

```py
password = ''

for typ in char_list:
    password += choice(type_chars[typ])

return password
```

as

```py
return "".join([choice(type_chars[typ]) for typ in char_list])
```

#### Functions

I'd probably put the following piece of code as a separate function to make it more modular and manageable

```py
# List that stores the "types" of possible character
char_list = []

# Mandatory requirements
for typ, val in zip(types.keys(), types.values()):
    char_list.extend([typ] * val)

# The remaining values to fill
for rem in range(length - num_chars):
    char_list.append(choice(list(types.keys())))

shuffle(char_list)
```

Likewise, with the suggested list comprehension that makes the password.

```py
def make_password(char_list)
    return "".join([choice(type_chars[typ]) for typ in char_list])
```

#### Optionals (fancy)

If you want to be very fancy, you can use `dataclasses` or `attrs` to package the options to the main function. This would allow you to make some validation of the input, namely, that everything you get are numbers (particularly `ints` or a string that can be parsed as such). Such a dataclass can be thought of as the communication layer between the front end (whatever is in the `__main__` part of the program) and the backend part in `generate_password`.

I say this because your program will fail if you don't give numbers. For example in the first logic line `num_chars = sum(list(types.values()))`.

Answer (score 2):

You can generate a password simply with the `random` module.

```
import string
import random

ls = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
length = random.randrange(6, 20) 
pwd = random.choices(ls, k=length)
print('new password: ', ''.join(pwd))
```

Output:

```
new password: xsC+.vrsZ<$\
```

Comment: Great idea! I should have thought of that! In the case of really needing to use the generator, I'll use this method. But right now, I'm trying to improve my programming skills! :-D